# Is it possible to create a python program that controls my web pages?

Tags: python, web, browser, automation

I have been wondering about this since I could really benefit from a program that makes actions on websites that I use for my job that require the same command over and over again.
I know some python and I love to learn new things.
I tried looking for it on google but I guess I'm not sure how to find it.
I would love it if you could direct me to a guide or something like that.
Thank you very much!

Comment: This seems to be off-topic. Please see [help/on-topic], [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do it with Python and some packages like selenium. Also you need some html knowledge to search in the html source code of the specific wegpage.

I found an interesting use case, maybe that helps you:
https://towardsdatascience.com/controlling-the-web-with-python-6fceb22c5f08

Answer (score 1):

Selenium interacts with a web browser directly, although you can hide the browser window in the code (look up Selenium in --headless mode). This is a good choice for filling out a lot of forms or interacting with graphical user interface elements.

However, if you need to request information from websites, you don't always need to interact with the web browser directly. You can use the package called [Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/). This doesn't depend on any web browsers and can run silently in the background.